# if statements and loops for project

Tags: java, project

Okay so I've built this program that reads a text file for grades and displays the top two students. I'm supposed to display any ties in grades, which I got working. However if there are no ties in the text file, it displays a duplicate second highest score. I can't seem to make it work so that if there are no ties it displays the two highest grades and if there are ties to displays two of the ties. I really need help. I've been struggling for hours trying to do this and I have to submit this before I go to bed tonight. Please somebody just help me fix this code, it's for a really big grade and I can't figure it out.

```
package lab06;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Lab06 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner lab06txt = new Scanner(new File("Lab06.txt")); //declare scanner for lab06.txt        
    //declare variables
    int grade = 0;
    int grade2 = 0;
    int record = 0;       
    int Highest = 0;
    int Highest2 = 0;
    int ACounter = 0;
    int BCounter = 0;
    int CCounter = 0;
    int DCounter = 0;
    int FCounter = 0;
    double average = 0;
    String lastName = "";
    String lastNameHigh = "";
    String lastNameHigh2 = "";
    String firstName = "";
    String firstNameHigh = "";
    String firstNameHigh2 = "";

    //while loop for lab06txt
    while (lab06txt.hasNext()){
        record ++; //keep track of number of records
        lastName = lab06txt.next(); //next string is placed into lastName
        firstName = lab06txt.next(); //next string is placed into firstName
        grade = lab06txt.nextInt(); //next integer is placed into grade
        {
            average += grade; //accumulate variable grade into variable average
            if (grade >= Highest) //if statement for determining highest grade 
            {
                Highest = grade;
                firstNameHigh = firstName; //places firstName of highest grade record into firstNameHigh
                lastNameHigh = lastName; //places lastName of highest grade record into lastNameHigh
            }                                       
        }

        {
        if ((grade >= 90) && (grade <= 100)) //if statements for variable grade
        {
           ACounter++;       //increases Acounter by 1
        }
        if ((grade >= 80) && (grade <= 89))
        {
           BCounter++;         //increases Bcounter by 1
        }
        if ((grade >= 70) && (grade <= 79))
        {
           CCounter++;         //increases Ccounter by 1
        }
        if ((grade >= 60) && (grade <= 69))
        {
           DCounter++;         //increases Dcounter by 1
        }
        if ((grade < 60))
        {
           FCounter++;         //increases Fcounter by 1
        }
        if ((grade < 0) || (grade > 100)) 
        {
            //if an incorrect error is found in the loop display the faulty record and end the program
            System.out.print("Score is out of bounds in record " + record + ": " + lastName + " "+ firstName + " " + grade + ".\nProgram ending\n"); 
            return;

        }
       }
    }
    Scanner SecondHighest = new Scanner(new File("Lab06.txt")); //new scanner for second highest grade
    while(SecondHighest.hasNext()) 
    {
        lastName = SecondHighest.next(); 
        firstName = SecondHighest.next();
        grade2 = SecondHighest.nextInt();           
        if(grade2 > Highest2 && grade2 < Highest) //if statement to determine second highest grade
        {
                Highest2 = grade2;
                firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
                lastNameHigh2 = lastName; 
        }
        if (Highest == grade2){
            Highest2 = grade2;
            firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
            lastNameHigh2 = lastName;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total students in class:        " +record); //display total students in class
    System.out.printf("Class average:                 %.1f\n", average/record); //display class average
    System.out.println("Grade Counters: "); 
    System.out.println("A's     B's     C's     D's     F's");
    System.out.printf(ACounter + "%7d %7d %8d %7d\n", BCounter,CCounter,DCounter,FCounter); //display number of A's B's C's D's and F's
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Top Two Students: \n"); 

    System.out.printf(lastNameHigh + " " + firstNameHigh + "%15d \n", Highest); //display highest score and student
    System.out.printf(lastNameHigh2 + " " + firstNameHigh2 + "%15d\n", Highest2); //display second highest score and student


}
```

}

The content of the text file follows this format:

```
Jackson Nicholas    96
James   Kevin       67
Jansen  David       92
Johnson Charlene    69
Jones   Nicole      83
Klein   Harry       97
```

Comment: If it's for a grade and you can't figure it out, then you shouldn't be graded well for figuring it out, should you?

Comment: ^ But I want to figure it out, I want to know what's wrong. It's been driving me mad all day. Even if not for the grade, this is gonna bother me and I've already spent ages trying to fix it, with no results. Which is why I'm here.

Comment: What's that static block doing there?  You know, the one after you assign `grade`?

Comment: Not really sure why I even put that there to be honest. It does nothing I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the amount of cleanup you should do with the code, this block seemed...*odd*.

```
while(SecondHighest.hasNext()) 
    {
        lastName = SecondHighest.next(); 
        firstName = SecondHighest.next();
        grade2 = SecondHighest.nextInt();           
        if(grade2 > Highest2 && grade2 < Highest) //if statement to determine second highest grade
        {
                Highest2 = grade2;
                firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
                lastNameHigh2 = lastName; 
        }
        if (Highest == grade2){
            Highest2 = grade2;
            firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
            lastNameHigh2 = lastName;
        }
    }
```

Specifically the second if statement:  It reads, "if highest is equal to grade2, then we overwrite highest2 with grade2, firstNameHigh2 with firstName, and lastNameHigh2 with lastName."

Why do we need that?  We're doing the same work in the statement above.  Delete it.

Now you're left with this:

```
while(SecondHighest.hasNext())  {
    lastName = SecondHighest.next(); 
    firstName = SecondHighest.next();
    grade2 = SecondHighest.nextInt();           
    if(grade2 > Highest2 && grade2 < Highest) {
        Highest2 = grade2;
        firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
        lastNameHigh2 = lastName; 
    }
}
```

It seemed to work - I get back Jackson Nicholas and Klein Harry as your top two students.  But does it cover the case when there is an equivalent score?

To test this case, I included another student on your list:  Naruto Uzumaki with a score of 97.  This would ensure that the highest two would be Klein Harry and Naruto Uzumaki.

I run it again, and I get Naruto Uzumaki and Jackson Nicholas as my top two students.  That can't be - there are two students with a tie in score!

I need to add an equivalence check to the if statement - grade2 should be greater than **or equal to** Highest2, and grade2 should be less than **or equal to** Highest to determine the second highest score.

Now, the fun part is to stop one name from squashing another.  I leave this as an exercise to the reader, but assuredly with the way your data is laid out, the first name that I read in can't be the *same* as the high score first name I read in, or it's the same person.

Now if only there were a way to see if two strings were equal...

Of course, doing it like that makes your code brittle to two users named "Jon" (I work with about three of 'em, so this would fail hardcore) - but perhaps it should be last name instead.  Think on it - it's an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I've done what you said and it still leaves me with the problem of when there are no ties, the scanner will read the text file and the second highest grade will be duplicated and I'll get the highest score displayed twice. I tried to change this by checking if the two strings for the last names were equal or not by doing the following.

Comment: `while(SecondHighest.hasNext()) 
  {
            if (!lastNameHigh.equals(lastNameHigh2)){
                tie = false;
                
            }
            lastName = SecondHighest.next(); 
            firstName = SecondHighest.next();
            grade2 = SecondHighest.nextInt();                      
            if(grade2 > Highest2 && grade2 < Highest && (tie = false)) //if statement to determine second highest grade
            {
                    Highest2 = grade2;
                    firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
                    lastNameHigh2 = lastName; 
         }}
` @Makoto

Comment: I actually figured it out thanks to you Makoto. "Now if only there were a way to see if two strings were equal.." I really appreciate you giving me the answer and making me think about it. I made two if statements for grade2. One where it is greater than or equal to Highest2 and one where it is just greater than. But inside the if statements I wrote `&& !lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(lastNameHigh))`